# How to forcefully import function from a module without removing other functions previously imported from it?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell module (*parent*), I want to forcefully import a function from another PowerShell module (*child*) without removing other functions previously imported from the child module (possibly by other parent modules).

Repro:

```bsh
# childmod.psm1 source

function Write-Foo {
    Write-Host "Foo"
}

function Write-Bar {
    Write-Host "Bar"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

```bsh
# interactive PS1 session

Import-Module "./childmod.psm1" -Function "Write-Foo" -Force

# This confirms "Write-Foo" function is available.
Get-Command -Module "childmod"

# This will remove the "Write-Foo" function!
Import-Module "./childmod.psm1" -Function "Write-Bar" -Force

# This confirms the "Write-Foo" function is no longer available!
Get-Command -Module "childmod"

# Now go and manually modify source of ./childmod.psm1 to make it output "Foo2" instead of "Foo".

# This will *not* remove "Write-Bar", 
# but it also will *not* update "Write-Foo" if its source has since changed.
Import-Module "./childmod.psm1" -Function "Write-Foo"

# This confirms both "Write-Foo" and "Write-Bar" functions are available.
Get-Command -Module "childmod"

# This confirms that still the old source of Write-Foo is used, as "Foo" will be printed out instead of "Foo2".
Write-Foo
```

PowerShell version used:

```bsh
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.18363
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

I considered simulating non-destructive force-import by first removing the function, and then importing without the -Force flag, but so far I was unable to figure out how to remove single imported function.

Possibly the right way to handle my use case is to use nested modules, as explained in [this tip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp#parameters):

> You should avoid calling `Import-Module` from within a module. Instead, declare the target module as a nested module in the parent module's manifest. Declaring nested modules improves the discoverability of dependencies.

Even if the nested modules are the right solution they require a bit more effort. I wonder if there is a a workaround that is simpler.

Related unanswered question from 4 years ago:
[Import-Module with -force removes imported module function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005664/import-module-with-force-removes-imported-module-function)

Related issue I opened against PowerShell: ["Import-Module -Force" erases $ErrorActionPreference variable value.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12808)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just import the module? Rather than trying to import individual functions?

Comment: I could do that. However, I hoped to keep the dependencies explicit and minimal. "The principle of least dependency", so to speak :)

Comment: maybe you could create a wrapper that takes the module and the cmdlet you want which then first checks if its loaded and if so which commands are loaded and then add the new cmdlet to the list of cmdlets to load and reload that module.

Comment: @Guenther yes, that is certainly an option. That would be some work, though, and I wonder if there is a simpler workaround (besides using module manifests with declarations of nested modules, which is also a somewhat nontrivial solution).